# pcap_compile for IPv6

Tags: ipv6, pcap, libpcap

I am making a networking program that will listen for ipv6 communication. I would like to use pcap library for this purpose. Unfortunately I am stuck at `int pcap_compile(pcap_t *p, struct bpf_program *fp, const char *str, int optimize, bpf_u_int32 netmask)` . It's last argument is IPv4 netmask, however my interface has only IPv6 address/mask.

I have been following these tutorials:

https://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html

http://yuba.stanford.edu/~casado/pcap/section1.html

I have also checked `man 3 pcap`, `man 3 pcap_compile` and tried some google-fu, however I have not find any information about how to use pcap library with IPv6 configured interface.

Is there any way to use pcap library for IPv6 interface? Prehaps something like pcap6 library? Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: The `netmask` argument is only used if the filter deals with IPv4 broadcast addresses, as far as I rememeber. Have you tried using PCAP_NETMASK_UNKNOWN?

Comment: Yea, I have reread the man page and tried it earlier today and it does exactly what I need. Just forgot to update my question. Next time I should remember not to panic at 2am.

Answer (score 0):

I past PCAP_NETMASK_UNKNOWN as netmask argument and everything works as intended.